# undetermined coefficients method leads riccardi without a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I try to find a general solution for the equation below
$$y'' = (x + y')^2$$

This way I wanted to transform it to a first order ode
$$y' = p$$ $$y'' = p'$$

This gives me the equation below which looks like a ricardi equation.

$$p' = p^2 + 2xp + x^2$$

The problem I am having here is that there is no solution given for riccardi. I am stuck at this step. How can I advance further? Or am I solving this wrong? Thanks

Comment: Maybe with the substitution $q=p+x$, you get $q' = q^2 + 1$?

Comment: You will find more references with the name "Riccati", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y''=(x+y')^2$$
Change of function : $y'=u(x)-x$
$$u'-1=u^2$$
This is a separable ODE.
$$\frac{du}{u^2+1}=dx$$
$$u=\tan(x+c_1)$$
$y'=\tan(x+c_1)-x$

$y=\int \left(\tan(x+c_1)-x\right)dx$
$$y=-\ln|\cos(x+c_1)|-\frac12 x^2+c_2$$